# So-DIMM to DIMM adapter?

Tags: memory, motherboard, adapter

I have some nice [4GB SO-DIMMs](http://www.memory4less.com/m4l_itemdetail.aspx?itemId=1443151823) from a broken workstation laptop that I would like to put to use in my desktop. Would this be possible? I did a bit of googling and found a [SoDIMM to DIMM adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005F0E26S) on amazon which seems to do what I need, but documentation concerning it is sparse to say the least. It claims to be for ram testing but one of the two comments on the item reported success in using it for his desktop. I currently have a Gigabyte GM-MA74GM motherboard (which is DDR2 unfortunately), but im planning to upgrade to something with DDR3 soon.

So my questions are:

- Can I use the aforementioned adapter with my current motherboard (or any other board) and utilize this SODIMM?
- Would there be significant performance impact?
- The comment on Amazon mentioned SPD, is this important?
- Should I just forget the adapter find a mini-itx motherboard?

Comment: More advice than answer. The adapter will not work with anything but a DDR3 board, once you upgrade your motherboard you can utilise the SO-DIMMS with the adapter. IMO memory is so fast regardless unless your a real enthusiast you wont notice a speed impact. SPD really depends on the board you buy, the only time I've had to mess around with SPD is when I tried to get ECC memory (server memory) to work on a workstation motherboard, I cannot see why SO-DIMM would cause a standard motherboard not to boot. Mini-ITX normally still come with full size DDR slots so you'll be in the same situation?...

Comment: @CharlesH Technically Thin-mini-ITX boards come with flat SO-DIMM slots to comply with height restriction. But Thin comes with many other limitations, not really worth it for 4GB of ram.